# ActiveAdmin, CanCan: privelegies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, cancan

I'm trying to set permissions for active_admin admins in my app. I want to separate admins for Administrators with full privilegies and Moderators who couldn't edit and destroy objects in ActiveAdmin admin panel.

ability.rb:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= AdminUser.new

    case user.role
    when 'admin'
      can :manage, :all
    when 'moderator'
      cannot [:destroy, :edit], :all
    end
  end
end
```

admin_user.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register AdminUser do

  permit_params :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :role

  index do
    selectable_column
    id_column
    column :email
    column :role
    column :current_sign_in_at
    column :sign_in_count
    column :created_at
    actions
  end

  filter :email
  filter :current_sign_in_at
  filter :sign_in_count
  filter :created_at

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Admin Details" do
      f.input :email
      f.input :password
      f.input :password_confirmation
      f.input :role, as: :radio, collection: { 'Administrator' => 'admin', 'Moderator' => 'moderator' }
    end
    f.actions
  end

end
```

The problem is admin with Moderator role still can edit and destroy objects. What did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

*@**railsdevmtl***, ActiveAdmin has it's own defined actions, so there is no need to override them in controller (in this particular case).

Answering the question: in order to make sure, that ability is checked somehow, I would recommend somewhat different approach:
First of all define `Ability` class methods as follows:

```
  def initialize(admin_or_moderator_user)
    if admin_or_moderator_user.kind_of?(AdminUser)
      admin_user_rules(admin_or_moderator_user)
    else
      moderator_rules(admin_or_moderator_user)
    end
  end

  def admin_user_rules(admin_user)
   can :manage, :all
  end
  def moderator_rules(moderator)
   cannot [:destroy, :edit] *modelname* # what is the point of restricting these actions - you only want to leave moderator with :update? so it is easier to define as can :update, *modelname*, *params*
  end
```

And what is very important - in `ApplicationController` define the `current_ability` method:

```
  def current_ability
    @current_ability ||= case
    when current_admin_user
      Ability.new(current_admin_user) #provided as default method by active_admin
    when current_moderator
      Ability.new(current_developer) # probably you'll need to define it, but this must not be difficult
    end
  end
```

Comment: as I understand you suggest to separate roles for `User` and `AdminUser` models. But I need to separate two roles for `AdminUser` only

Comment: O, my mistake. I think the issue hides in this `cannot [:destroy, :edit], :all` line. Instead of `:all` you most likely would have to define the model on which you restrict the actions. (if there more, than one model - define them in separate lines)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the following on your controller for destroy and update action?

```
def destroy
  @foo = Foo.find(params[:id])
  authorize! :destroy, @foo
end

def update
  @foo = Foo.find(params[:id])
  authorize! :update, @foo
end
```

And on your views for edit something like:

```
<% if can? :update, @foo %>
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_foo_path(@foo) %>
<% end %>
```

you can follow similar approach with `:destroy` action.